# Grep on a single column in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I'm trying to parse `df -h` command's output. For example:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VGExaDb-LVDbSys1
                       30G   17G   12G  58% /
/dev/sda1             496M   38M  433M   8% /boot
/dev/mapper/VGExaDb-LVDbOra1
                       99G   18G   76G  19% /u01
tmpfs                 252G   90M  252G   1% /dev/shm
dbfs-dbfs_user@:/     4.0T  283G  3.7T   8% /dbfs_direct
```

I only want values under "Avail" column. But `awk` command doesn't work as i wanted, because number of words in each line is not the same. When i run `df -h | awk '{print $4}'` command, it gives the output like this:

```
Avail

58%
433M

19%
252G
3.7T
```

Comment: +1 to restore the karma. Your question looks fine to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
df -Ph | awk '{ print $4 }'
```

Per `man` page:

```
   -P, --portability
          use the POSIX output format
```

This won't lead to unnecessary line breaks. `h` will give you in human readable format.

Comment: I found this solution just a minute before you but thanks, marking it  :)

Answer (score 2):

personally I think use `--output` option of `df` is the right way to go:

```
df -h --output='avail'
```

Comment: When i try to run this, here i get:
-bash: avail: command not found
df: unrecognized option `--output='
Try `df --help' for more information.

Comment: @AloneInTheDark Please try this `df -h --output=avail`

Comment: df: unrecognized option `--output=avail'
Try `df --help' for more information.

Comment: @AloneInTheDark Which Linux distribution are you using? Does your `df` come from GNU coreutils?

Comment: I'm trying to run this on rhel

Comment: @Kent The `-P` option for `df` is better suited in this case, but it won't give _human-readable_ sizes.

Comment: @devnull if OP's `df` was the same version as mine, I think `-h --output=...` is the right way to go. If `--output` option is not available for him. Then other tool (awk/sed...) may be needed.

Comment: @Kent I should have added that I'm currently on BSD; it seems that on other variants `-h` works with `-P` (referring to the other answer).

Comment: @Kent After some inspection of the history of GNU coreutils `df`, it turns out that this `--output` option is quite new, added Aug, 30, 2012.

Comment: @leeduhem oh, I didn't notic that. I am using bleeding-edged  archlinux. :-D :-D

Comment: @Kent Me too. BTW, the earliest version of GNU coreutils which has this `--output` option is 8.20, released at Oct 23, 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty? Try this:

```
df -h | grep / | awk '{print $4}'
```

Update: It works, even with line breaks when using a console geometry that's set to 40 columns only:
[image]

Comment: no, it's not working. it's just same as i runned before, as you can see in my question.

Comment: no, it's not the same, it only outputs the 4th column of lines with a "/" in it. Just give it a try.

Comment: Then your system must be f*cked up in a way ;) Please see my updated answer. The command I gave you also works when using a very small console size. This was done on a standard Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: +1 for your output but i'm using rhel. also i found the solution, please check it.

Comment: @Robert if your line worked, the cmd from OP should work too, you can test there, remove the `grep` part.